# TextView setVisibility not working in ViewPager Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I am unable to set the visibility of the text view to VISIBLE.GONE in my fragment.

My fragment layout:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="b5.project.medibro.fragments.PrescriptionsFragment">


<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/prescriptions_list"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_input_add" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/noItems"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textColor="@color/myPrimaryColor"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/no_medi_items" />

 </FrameLayout>
```

I have instantiated the textview correctly but unable to debug the code. Any suggestions regarding this issue?
My Fragment java code is

```
public class PrescriptionsFragment extends Fragment {

private static final String TAG = PrescriptionsFragment.class.getSimpleName();
FloatingActionButton fab;
ListView prescriptionsList;
private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;
private ArrayList<Medication> medications;
TextView tv;
public PrescriptionsFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_prescriptions, container, false);

    tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.noItems);
    tv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    fab = (FloatingActionButton) v.findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), AddPrescription.class));
        }
    });

    medications = new ArrayList<>();
    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getActivity());
    HashMap<Integer, Medication> hashMap = db.getMedicationDetails();

    if (hashMap.isEmpty()) {
        tv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "hashmap size: " + hashMap.size());
        tv.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        for (int i = 0; i < hashMap.size(); i++) {
            medications.add(i, hashMap.get(i));
        }
        prescriptionsList = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.prescriptions_list);
        prescriptionsList.setAdapter(new MyMedAdapter(getActivity(), "all", medications));
    }
    return v;
}

}
```

My logcat snippet:

```
03-31 11:33:03.986: D/Database Handler(13900): selectQuery: SELECT * FROM     medication
03-31 11:33:03.987: D/Database Handler(13900): Fetching: Test1
03-31 11:33:03.987: D/PrescriptionsFragment(13900): hashmap size: 1
03-31 11:33:03.988: D/FeedFragment(13900): onResume
```

Can someone tell what's wrong with this code?

Comment: check `if (hashMap.isEmpty()) {}` in your code it would be Empty or not

Comment: No its not. I have checked the logs. The log cat is displaying hasmap size.

Comment: you forgot to make hashmap object

Comment: HashMap<Integer, Medication> hashMap = new HashMap <Integer, Medication>();  hashMap=db.getMedicationDetails();

Comment: @AmitRanjan No i didn't. The function `db.getMedicationDetails();` returns a new instantiated hashmap with some items fetched from the db.

Comment: `if(v==null){ tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.noItems);
    tv.setVisibility(View.GONE);}`

Comment: Is Your Textview for Displaying nothing in listview...?

Comment: So are you wondering why your ListView doesn't display anything when the HashMap is not empty?

Comment: you can set the visibility gone in onActivityCreated

Comment: @DougStevenson if there are no items for listview, then I want the textview to be visible. If there are items to be displayed, then I want the listview to be gone.

Comment: pls tell me hash map size or value?

Comment: so you use `prescriptionsList.setEmptyView(tv);` and you not require to Enable/Disable `Textview`

Comment: @AbhijithGururaj So what exactly is not displaying correctly according to your description?  I can't tell what what is going wrong.

Comment: you told your logcat is displaying size of hashmap then how can it set visibility.GONE .

Comment: when your hash map is not empty than what is your output?

Comment: pls add your logcat screenshot

Comment: Please check the logcat snippet now.

Comment: use this tv.setVisibility(v.GONE);

Comment: @AbhijithGururaj please add your Manifest file

Comment: @DougStevenson All I want is to display the text view when the hashmap is empty. The textView is still visible even though the hashmap has items in it. I'm unable to understand this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
 prescriptionsList.setEmptyView(tv);
```

for displaying no data in `listview`

Comment: Thanks! This worked. Also, I removed the if condition and moved the fetch from db and set adapter code to onResume method in order to avoid some other bugs. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Set Your text view visibility at

```
 public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
}
```

or in

```
 @Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
}
```

will work

Answer (score 0):

noItems textView Gone from your layout file and **setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);**
From Programmatically if you need.

OR

Try

```
 public static final int VISIBLE = 0x00000000;

 /**
  * This view is invisible, but it still takes up space for layout purposes.
  * Use with {@link #setVisibility}.
  */
 public static final int INVISIBLE = 0x00000004
 public static final int GONE = 0x00000008;

 tv.setVisibility(GONE );
```

Comment: Why did you include source code? `View.GONE` works fine.